# ubuntu 16.04 mysql-server install error

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I have problems installing mysql-server on my Ubuntu 16.04:

Installation command:
`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

I've tried doing a complete uninstall and purge of mysql using the following lines:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```

And when reinstalling I get the prompt to set a root password for mysql server.
However midway during insallation I get the error

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libevent-core-2.0-5 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7
  mysql-common mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libevent-core-2.0-5 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7
  mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/18.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 160 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 316748 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libaio1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libaio1_0.3.110-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libaio1:amd64 (0.3.110-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-core-5.7_5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.7_5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.7_5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libevent-core-2.0-5_2.0.21-stable-2ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-2ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.7.
(Reading database ... 316916 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.2) ...
Setting up libaio1:amd64 (0.3.110-2) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-2ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-07-03 16:31:40 +08; 15ms ago
  Process: 11464 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11463 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 11454 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11463 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 03 16:31:40 NEOZEN systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Jul 03 16:31:40 NEOZEN systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 03 16:31:40 NEOZEN systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-...'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried googling for solutions but all of them lead me back to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting my computer fixed this somehow.